# What is the fastest communication between tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I want to use Google Chrome or a fork of Chromium as a studio for data browsing and transformation.
I know extensions have a messaging api but I wanted to see if anyone knew a way to coordinate work or content rendering between tabs or windows in Chrome.

Is there something faster and/or more flexible than chrome extensions for communicating between tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local storage is a good way to communicate as long as the tabs are on the same domain.